# Is it possible to have multi part actions in the route?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Ok so a typical route might look like this:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

The problem is that our existing endpoints look like this

```
{controller}/Somesortofgrouping/{action}
```

On example of this is our payments controller. We might have the following endpoints:

```
payment/credit/sale
payment/credit/refund
payment/cash/sale
```

And the method names would be, respectively:

```
CreditSale();
CreditRefund();
CashSale();
```

So rather than having to add every endpoint to the WebApiConfig in order to preserve our convention, is there any way use a template to work with this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding every endpoint to the config, you may consider using the excellent **[AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/)** package and **configure routes on the controller/actions itself using attributes**.

Some restrictions apply to Web API (as listed in the documentation) as compared to MVC.

After having used this library, it's difficult to imagine going back to maintain a separate configuration of routes.

Comment: Indeed, but it doesn't seem to allow me to prefix the method uri. So the method is CreditRefund, but the uri is cash/refund. The moment i add a / to the uri in the attribute, it breaks.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the linked library? You can name the action method anything you like, and add an attribute like this: `[GET("payment/cash/refund")]` (and as soon as you get it working, you may take `payment` out and add it as a `RoutePrefix` attribute on the controller). See also the examples on http://attributerouting.net/#defining-routes

Comment: I definitely am. Not quite sure what's going on, everything else seems to work fine including the RoutePrefix